# Android Studio - Open JS Debugger does not open Browser

Tags: react-native, android-studio, google-chrome, expo

I wanted to create an App with React Native.

The Project is run with Expo.

When using the "Open JS Debugger", chrome doesnt open and the Terminal is showing this error:

> Error launching JS inspector: [LaunchBrowser] Unable to find a browser on the host to open the inspector. Supported browsers: Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge

When pressing "j", to open the "open debugger" in the Terminal when running the Metro bundler, I get this error:
[errorMessage2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfRZw.png)

When reloading the App while being in the debugger ui, the js file which should appear in the source tab, doesnt appear.
http://localhost:19000/debugger-ui/

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIfOA.png)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "gizapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~48.0.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Reinstalling Android Studio
Trying multiple Devices and APIs in Android Studio

Just wanna be able to debug.

Comment: I'm guessing you do use either Chrome or Edge? If so, make sure to install the React Developer tools extension, and check if there is any configuration needed for your tools to select your browser.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same too. This works before without any extra config

Comment: developer experience using expo and vscode is so overrated.  i get the following trying to open debugger after `expo start -c`

`› Toggling dev menu
Error launching JS inspector: _open(...).default.openApp is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-hermes/#setup

> Can I use Remote Debugging with Hermes? One of the many limitations of
> remote debugging is that it does not work with modules built on top of
> JSI. For example, if your app uses react-native-reanimated version 2
> or higher, remote debugging will not work.
>
> Hermes supports Chrome DevTools Protocol to debug JavaScript in place
> by connecting to the running engine on the device. This enables you to
> debug your app even when using JSI modules. This debugging technique
> is superior to remote debugging and replaces it for apps using Hermes.

So basically you cant debug if you have a drawer from @react-navigation/drawer component...because it uses reanimated...